# Startswith with a range of number instead an unit

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, range, startswith

```
ip = a list of ips
ipf = list(filter(lambda x: x if not x.startswith(str(range(257,311))) else None, ip))
```

Is is possible to do something like this? I tested it and it doesn't work.
I'd like to delete all ips from "ip" list that start with 256. 257. 258. ecc... to 310.

Comment: The parts of a valid IP will be in the range 0 to 255 (both inclusive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `str.startswith()` doesn't take a range.

You'd have to parse out the first part and test it as an integer; filtering is also easier done with a list comprehension:

```
[ip for ip in ip_addresses if 257 <= int(ip.partition('.')[0]) <= 310]
```

The alternative would be to use the [`ipaddress` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html); it'll reject any invalid address with a `ipaddress.AddressValueError` exception, and since addresses that start with anything over 255 are invalid, you can easily co-opt that to filter out your invalid addresses:

```
import ipaddress

def valid_ip(ip):
    try:
        ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip)
    except ipaddress.AddressValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

[ip for ip in ip_addresses if valid_ip(ip)]
```

Comment: so in my case I need to use:     ipf = [x for x in ip if 257 <= int(x.partition('.')[0]) <= 310]     right?

Comment: @Thavivelball: yes; I renamed `ip` to `ip_addresses` to use clearer variable names.

Comment: @Thavivelball: since you didn't provide any sample input dat or the expected output, I can't help you more than this.

Comment: It works actually.... just you mistyped lol... you typed "ipaddress.IPV4Address(ip)" instead of "ipaddress.IPv4.Address(ip)". Thanks

Comment: Corrected; it was typed from memory.

Comment: @Thavivelball: that's not an [mcve]. Please isolate the wrong results that you expected not to be added to the blacklist.